# Setting M Values to nearest foot

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, digitizing, trace

I am using 10.8.2, is there a way that after I draw a line the M Values can be auto-rounded to the nearest foot, without me going to "edit sketch" and changing them myself? All I am doing is tracing over plats to get the approximate location of items and all M Values have to be to the nearest foot.

Comment: What is an M Value?

Comment: M-values are used to measure the distance along a line feature from a vertex

Comment: Witch M value do you really need to be at the nearest foot ? those at the line vertex or those in the events table ?

Comment: I mean having vertex value rounded to the nearest foot wont prevent locating event to some decimal value

Comment: So what I was told to do is trace over the plat, and after that go into the "Edit Sketch Properties"  where you see the X, Y, Z, and M values of each vertex. And in that location go thru and round all M values to the nearest foot, then save edits. So what I was hoping for is a way to make the process automated. This way it is more efficient and less likely to have errors from my changing values.

Comment: If you where told to do it then there are are way to use the field calculator to edit M value, see this : https://support.esri.com/en-us/knowledge-base/how-to-edit-measure-m-values-with-the-field-calculator-000003837 for related exemple on editing M value...

Comment: To automate this will need ArcPy.